# Swing designed form from GroupLayout to GridBagLayout design

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8, gridbaglayout, grouplayout

I have designed a application form in Java SWING. With the internal frame to get user input.

The application works fine; but fails in UI, based on different screen sizes. I have used the `GroupLayout` system in the Netbeans, whilst designing. After that I found out, I need to use `GridBagLayout` for flexible to multiple size screens. Is there any way to change it in Netbeans Swing? Share some examples or reuse of the code.

Main problem is: The form designed is designed in 15.6 inch screen, is not fit with the square shaped screen (i.e) 14 inch screen.

Note: The internal frame remains constant, whatever be the screen size.

Comment: So, your question is: How to easily change a Swing Application from GroupLayout to GridBagLayout using Netbeans?

Comment: @Alexander, Obviously

Comment: `GroupLayout` & `GridBagLayout` have different layout philosophies and it would take human level intelligence to decide best how to translate a GUI from one to the other. Having said that, no layout will guarantee a square GUI, so you might as well just design in in a form that looks visually appealing and then add the collection of containers and controls to a scroll pane before adding them to the top level window. *"Share some examples.."* Pay me money before ordering me around.